# increasing efficiency of cosine simarlity

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, sentence-similarity

So I'm trying to find similar sentences in a moderately large file with 60000 rows. Now to accomplish this, I first created sentence encodings of each row using google universal sentence encoder. Then I use this to compare cosine similarity and find similar sentences

```
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4" 
model = hub.load(module_url)

sentence_embeddings = model(sentences)


def cosine(u, v):
    return numpy.dot(u, v) / (numpy.linalg.norm(u) * numpy.linalg.norm(v))

for idx,query in list(enumerate(sentences)):
    for idx2,sente in enumerate(sentences):
        if idx1 == idx2:
            continu
        sim = cosine(sentence_embeddings[idx], sentence_embeddings[idx2])
        if sim >= .80:
            # store in output
```

So with `60000^2` operations of cosine similarity, it takes days on my device to execute this code. Is there a way I can do this faster. I understand that this is probably as fast as I can get with python so if the solution involves using some other language, im open to it as well

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 ideas that might help you.

**1st** : Try to do the same thing using c++ : generate the enccodings with python then transfert them to a c++ program that will do the operations faster.

**2nd** : Try to use approximations. You can take a look at LSH (Locality sensitive hashing) take a look at this https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-locality-sensitive-hashing-49f6d1f6134